# Why does linear_congruential_engine::seed(Sseq) discard three numbers generated by the seed sequence?

Tags: c++

The C++ standard (all the way from C++11 to the current C++17 draft) says the following in [rand.eng.lcong]:

> ```
> template<class Sseq> explicit linear_congruential_engine(Sseq& q);
> ```
>
> *Effects:* Constructs a `linear_congruential_engine` object. With *k* = ⌈log<sub>2</sub>(*m*) ÷ 32⌉ and *a* an array 32 (or equivalent) of length *k* + 3, invokes `q.generate(a + 0, a + k + 3)` and then computes *S* = (∑<sub>*j*=0</sub><sup>*k*−1</sup> *a*<sub>*j*+3</sub> · 2<sup>32​*j*</sup>) mod *m*. If *c* mod *m* is 0 and *S* is 0, sets the engine’s state to 1, else sets the engine’s state to S.

Why are *a*<sub>0</sub>, *a*<sub>1</sub> and *a*<sub>2</sub> discarded?

Comment: Is `Sseq` equal to `std::seed_sequence`? If yes, then I don't see why anything should be discarded. Are you *really* sure it *is*?

Comment: Originated in [N2079](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2079.pdf), which is short on the rationale.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, `Sseq` here refers to a seed sequence as defined in [rand.req.seedseq] such as `std::seed_seq`, as far as I can tell from the introduction to random number engine class templates [rand.eng] and the random number engine requirements [rand.req.eng].

Answer (score 1):

This is something I've been trying to figure out myself. I had a hypothesis, but no real evidence for it. However, the document the rule originated in ([N2079](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2079.pdf) as linked by @T.C.) confirmed part of my theory.

Note that the function that the rule comes from takes in a `std::seed_seq` object in the document, and not a templated class. This means that when the rule was written, it was made specifically for `std::seed_seq`, and not the concept of a SeedSequence in general. This means that we can look at the `std::seed_seq` class for information about this, specifically with how `std::seed_seq::generate` is defined.

The method that `std::seed_seq::generate` uses is well explained [on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/seed_seq/generate). It's a bit complicated, but it can be summarized in 4 stages.

1. Initialize the output range with some initial data (I'm including `k=0` here)
2. Move the original seed data into the output range (`k=1..s`)
3. Extend the seed data into the rest of the output range (`k=s+1..m-1` where `m=max(s+1, n)`)
4. Shuffle the data in the output range (`k=m..m+n-1`)

When seeding a `std::linear_congruential_engine` with the modulo <= 2<sup>32</sup> (which includes `std::minstd_rand` and `std::minstd_rand0`), it should only need to generate 1 value from `std::seed_seq`, but with this rule, it generates 4. So what changes in this algorithm when changing `n` from 1 to 4?

One part that changes is that the shuffling stage goes from 1 iteration to 4. Since one of the goals of `std::seed_seq` is to produce high quality seeding values "given a small seed or a poorly distributed initial seed sequence.`, these extra shuffling iterations likely improve the resulting seed value. The reason why it drops the first 3 values instead of the last is because the later values are (usually) the ones that get shuffled more.

It's also worth noting that a key equation of all 4 stages is the value `begin[k]^begin[k+p]^begin[k−1]` (with XOR replaced with addition in the last stage). When `n=1`, this simply becomes `begin[k]` (or `3*begin[k]` for the last stage) (note that "the indexing of the output range `begin[x]` is taken modulo n" and `x % 1 == 0`). When `n=4`, this equation works more like it was intended to, which helps shuffle the data around more effectively.

So the short answer is that `std::linear_congruential_engine` discards 3 numbers generated by the seed sequence because having `std::seed_seq` generate those numbers improves the quality of the values it actually uses. Now, the decision to discard these numbers in the generator was decided before the *generic concept* of SeedSequence was defined, so it made more sense to solve the issue in the generator, instead of overcomplicating the seed sequence class. However, this now means that the first 3 values generated by **any** seed sequence are discarded. Whether or not that's worth it is probably debatable, but it is the way it is now.